# How to remove square bracket from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array..let say:

```
$array = [$a,$b,$c,$d];
```

How I can remove `[` and `]`?

The expected result would be:

```
$a,$b,$c,$d
```

I used some array function e.g `array_slice` but it does not fill my requirement. Any ideas?

**Note:** I need to pass all array elements to function as argument.

```
e.g: function example($a,$b,$c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like you're after a string representation of the array, try using [`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) or [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like this:

```
<?php
$array = [$a,$b,$c,$d];
$str = join(",", $array); // OR $str = implode(",", $array);
echo $str;
```

**EDIT**

after reading your question a little more carefully, you're trying to pass the array into a function call, to do that you need to use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
<?php
function function_name($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4){
    //do something here
}
$array = [$a,$b,$c,$d];
call_user_func_array('function_name', $array);
```